# Extracting out a text variable in a sentence template to be replace by a random text

Tags: java, collections, split

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class split {
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int count=0;
        ArrayList<String> template= new ArrayList<String>;

        String sentence ="$name1 went to the fruit stall with $int1 pieces of $5-notes. $name1 bought $int2 $fruit1 and $int3 $fruit2. Each $fruit1 cost $$decimal10. Each $fruit2 cost $$decimal20. How much money had $name1 left? ( Leave your answer to one decimal place )";

        String[] words = sentence.split(" ");

        for(int i=0; i< words.length;i++) {

            System.out.println(i+": "+words[i]);
            if(words[i].equals("$fruit")) {
                System.out.println("$fruit is in this template");           
            }

            if(words[i].equals("$name1")) {
                System.out.println("$name1 is in this template");
                count++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("$name1 Appears "+ count + " times." );
}
}
```

I have a sentence template as shown above. Which is the

```
String sentence ="$name1 went to the fruit stall with $int1 pieces of $5-notes. $name1 bought $int2 $fruit1 and $int3 $fruit2. Each $fruit1 cost $$decimal10. Each $fruit2 cost $$decimal20. How much money had $name1 left? ( Leave your answer to one decimal place )";
```

I just want to process the sentence template and extract all the text template variables like $name1, $int1 and etc etc. They will be replaced by a suitable text in which I have made a random generator and combine them back to the sentence to make a complete sentence.

I have tried the split above to extract out the text variable template (eg:$name1, $int1 and etc etc ). It works but I am finding a more simpler way and shorter way. Because for loop the processing time will be slow if I have a long paragraph.

I have read about Collections.But couldn't figure out if it could be of use in my situation. Any one have any comments or any idea that you may have done it before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 
replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
from String. See javadoc 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

```
 String str = text.replaceAll(pattern, "text"); ;
```

You can do this for all your vars, or better yet, use Matcher and Pattern
It is described very thoroughly in this [blog](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Consider accepting my answer if satisfies your question.